# JDBC ERROR:08S01 sometimes happens

Tags: java, mysql, multithreading, jdbc

> SQLState relac: 08S01, thread:0
>
> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
>
> The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
>   ...  more
>
> Caused by: java.net.SocketException: No buffer space available (maximum connections reached?): connect
>       at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
>       at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:351)
>       at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:213)
>       at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:200)
>       at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
>       at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
>       at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:478)
>       at java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:375)
>       at java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:218)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:257)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.(MysqlIO.java:294)
>       ... 20 more

I working with N threads and it happens just sometimes not in a specific time( X minutes)

I try with diferent driver but i can't solve the problem.

Comment: If you are using Windows it may be solved by https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/196271

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're most likely either

1. Opening sockets and not closing them.  Over time the number of open sockets gets too large and the application crashes.
2. You're opening way too many sockets at the same time.  Maybe because you have a ton of threads.

I'm going to guess it's #1.  Double check your code and make sure that you close all your Connection objects and ResultSet objects.

If you're running into #2 then you may want to consider using fewer threads (after a certain point having too many threads does more harm than good) or using a connection pool like [c3p0](http://sourceforge.net/projects/c3p0/) which will only create a set number of connections and allow your threads to share them.  Using c3p0 is a good idea in general and should also allow you to detect #1 faster.

A third option is to use a higher level abstraction such as JPA or JDO which will take care of connection management for you.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I tried to close ResultSet,Statement,Conection and I used c3po but the error still  :(      
I used only 3 or 4 Threads, but I make a lot of transaction.

Comment: Hey Pace, my mistakes, i try again with c3p0 and now works excellent :D you are my hero.... thanks a lot

Comment: @Rodri_gore, i am slo using c3p0 , but still getting the same error ...can you tell me what config helped you?

Answer (score 0):

In my case we're use MsSQL server and application on JBoss server based on JbossSeam framework. 
This error is due to version mismatch of hibernate and hsqldb. Trying updating latest verion of both libraries and error will be gone. e.g. in below maven, hibernate 4.3.6.Final is perfectly compitable with hsqldb version 2.2.9.
This way helped us