# MySQL: [08S01] Communications link failure

Tags: mysql, intellij-idea

I have an application with local DB, which is H2. But customer is using MySQL. There were some issues on customer side, so I decided to install and run an application against MySQL on local machine (MacOS). I am using java 9.

1. [Download MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/file/?id=475582)
2. Install
3. [Follow very easy how to from jetbrains](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/connecting-to-a-database.html)

Current setup:
[image]
[image]

After click on "Test Connection" I am getting following error.

[image]

There is a lot of comments:

[packet drops or badly configured Firewall/Switch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16459990/sql-error-0-sqlstate-08s01-communications-link-failure)

[a lot of transaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6480573/jdbc-error08s01-sometimes-happens)

[known bug - solution in maven dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11714042/openshift-mysql-communications-link-failure)

But most of them are not in test connection, but in configuration. Also the connection for those guys works at least once or through another set of firewalls. None of the previous solutions fit my case.

I also try to restart MySQL with:

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

With the result:

```
service: command not found
```

Or just to check the status with:

```
sudo service mysql status
```

With the result:

```
service: command not found
```

I dont know if it is connected to my issue? Is db running "forever" or idea will run it only when I will run the app? Could anyone help with connection to db?

Comment: `sudo mysql -root -p restart` try this one

Comment: With result:    sudo: mysql: command not found

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/82374/how-do-i-start-stop-mysql-server Check this link may help you

Comment: I tried with no result. After all I restarted and it showed me error message with expired password (which was one from mysql, I never changed it). To change password I have to install MySQL workbench, change pass and now it works. Anyway thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried with no result. After all I restarted and it showed me error message with expired password (which was one from mysql, I never changed it). To change password I have to install MySQL workbench, change pass and now it works. Anyway thank you!

Answer (score 12):

I simply changed the driver to Amazon Aurora MySQL despite having a simple mysql database on a VPS.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, changing the driver was the solution> I've changed it from mysql to amazon aurora mysql

Answer (score 7):

I ran into similar error when trying have JetBean Datagrip and Pycharm to connect to mySQL server hosted by Amazon.

I am able to fix this issue by using an earlier version of my SQL driver.

For example:

[image]

Comment: This has just saved me

Answer (score 0):

For me, I don't know why, IntelliJ Idea suddenly raise a error `Communications link failure java.net.ConnectException` when I start any projects.

I checked the connection on `My SQL Workbench`, it worked fine. And I tried to restart my pc and the error is gone